# NxWorkspace, Angular: What is the purpose of splitting compilerOptions in tsconfig.lib.json

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx, nrwl

What is the purpose of tsconfig.lib.json in my NxWorkspace?

I have a single Angular app in my workspace.

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "declaration": true,
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "jest.config.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}

tsconfig.lib.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["jest.config.ts", "**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

1. What's the point in splitting 'compilerOptions' this way? Is there a valid reason, or was it just careless programming?
2. I assume I can move the compiler options from tsconfig.lib.json to tsconfig.json and everything should work fine. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is by design and it is not a careless programming. They want to make `libs` as independent as possible. Thus, they offer the advantage of defining your custom `TypeScript` configuration at that point, so that you can set the bounderies of your library very well and libs have more potential configuration available.

To your point, yes you can define a root `tsconfig` in your `nx` workspace. In fact, it is called `tsconfig.base.json`. According to the official documentation:

> /tsconfig.base.json sets up the global TypeScript settings and creates
> aliases for each library to aid when creating TS/JS imports.

Comment: I wasn't curious about tsconfig.base.json, but both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.lib.json. Also both these files are in every library created by nx lib generator. Therefore I don't see a point in having both files in the workspace and I have no idea why the 'compilerOptions' are split.

Comment: because there is also more to it: a) how to define different tsconfig for test and build? b) how to ignore somefiles when launched from root of repo? c) how to define only the files for use in other packages?